# Toshiba Notebook Won't Boot

Tags: boot

I have a 16 month old Toshiba Notebook NB525-00H. I replaced the original 1GB memory card with a Crucial 2GB memory upgrade (2GB 204-PIN DDR3 SODIMMPC3-10600 CL3). I was very careful not to touch the surface of the memory card. It went in perfectly with no problem as per instructions.

When I tried to boot it, the power light came on, but the drive light comes on for only a second then goes out. I can hear the fan continuing to run but nothing appears on the screen. There's no effect if I try to use any F key when attempting a startup.

If I reinsert the original 1GB memory card, the same thing happens. There's no debris in the connection for the memory card.

Both the notebook and the memory card are out of warranty.

How can I get it running again?

Comment: does the laptop beep at you?  If so, what are the beeps?  Short, long, how many of each each and in what order.  Also try removing all the memory and boot, see if you get any beeps.

Comment: No, there are no beeps with or without the memory.

Comment: if there are no beeps, that isnt a good sign.  Especially since the old memory does not work.

Comment: Any other ideas?

Comment: impossible to say for sure, but it sounds like the motherboard may be dead.  Check with Toshiba for authorized service centers in your area.  It might easier on you to have them check it out.

Comment: OK Thanx for your help.